# React native SectionList horizontal mode

Tags: react-native

I've got a question. I've been trying to use SectionList for render a list section but the problem is I want to use list in horizontal mode and I don't know how to do that.

Please help I've stuck on this for 2 hours.

**This is my code:**

```
<SectionList
   renderItem={({item}) => <Image source={require('../assets/images/img1.jpg')} />}
   renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Text>{section.title}</Text>}
   sections={dataSource}
/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ReactNative docs, there is no prop for making horizontal SectionList(as of 0.48), but its parent VirtualizedList has.
Hence just try if it works ...

```
<SectionList
   horizontal={true}
/>
```

If it does not work then probably u should try using **Flatlist** which has a horizontal prop and wait until it's implemented for **SectionList**