# How to handle flatlist item data in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using React-native Flat List in which i have passed sorted array into data props.Now i want to show items according to date
MY code :

```
 <FlatList
   horizontal={true}
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
   data={this.state.Data}
   renderItem={({ item }) =>
     <View>
       <Image source = {{uri: item.image}}/>
       <Text>{item.date}</Text>
     </View>                           
    }
 />
```

I want my image show according to item.date.For example :

```
Date - 20-09-2018
Image1 ..Image 2...
Date - 21-09-2018
Image1..Image2 ...
```

Help me !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) for this purpose as it provides good API for handling such cases.

```
<SectionList
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
    sections={list || []}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
/>
```

For that you need to map your data and create something like an array of objects as

```
[
    {
        heading: 'Date - 20-09-2018',
        data: [Image1, Image2]
    },
    {
        heading: 'Date - 21-09-2018',
        data: [Image1, Image2]
    }
]
```

So the renderSectionHeader function will be something like:

```
renderSectionHeader = ({section}) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{section.heading}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

And all the other functions like renderItem, renderSeparator etc. you can define as you want.

[Check this link for more info](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist)

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'section.data.length') they gave me error like this

Comment: Where did u tried `section.data.length`.In `renderSectionHeader()` ??

Comment: But there is problem and that is :

Comment: Date:
Img1,
img2
Date :
Img1

i dont want vertically ... i want to show all images horizontally

Comment: just add this `horizontal={true}` .Found from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452773/react-native-sectionlist-horizontal-mode